# Partial View returning Null model ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Within my MainView, I was able to render all the "TaskComment"(model) using _GetForTask partial view. Then within my _GetForTask partial view, I was able to render _TaskCommentForm and successfull passed a new instance of TaskComment model. However, whenever I click the "Submit" button in the _TaskCommentForm partial view, it always returns null. What am I missing here? Thanks a lot.

"TaskComment" model

```
public partial class TaskComment
{
    public int TaskCommentID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TaskID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my "MainView"

```
@Html.Action("_GetForTask", "TaskComment", new { TaskID = Model.TaskID })
```

_GetForTask PartialView

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectYesha.Models.TaskComment>
<div id="comments">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var taskComment in Model)
        {
            <li>@taskComment.Comment</li>
        }
    </ul>  
    @using (Html.BeginForm("_Submit", "TaskComment", FormMethod.Post))
    { 
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Action("_TaskCommentForm", "TaskComment", new { TaskID = ViewBag.TaskID })
    }

</div>
```

_TaskCommentForm PartialView

```
@model ProjectYesha.Models.TaskComment

@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.TaskCommentID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.TaskID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.AuthorID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.TimeStamp)

@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.Employee)
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.Task)
<div>   
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    { 
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TaskID)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Comment)
        <input type="submit" value = "Submit" />
    }
</div>
```

TaskCommentController

```
 public PartialViewResult _GetForTask(Int32 taskID)
        {
            ViewBag.TaskID = taskID;
            List<TaskComment> comments = db.TaskComments.Where(c => c.TaskID == taskID).ToList();
            return PartialView("_GetForTask", comments);
        }

        [ChildActionOnly()]
        public PartialViewResult _TaskCommentForm(Int32 taskID)
        {

            TaskComment comment = new TaskComment() 
            {
                TaskID = taskID ,
            };
            return PartialView("_TaskCommentForm", comment);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
        public PartialViewResult _Submit(TaskComment comment)
        {
            db.TaskComments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();

            List<TaskComment> comments = db.TaskComments.Where(c => c.TaskID == comment.TaskID).ToList();
            ViewBag.TaskID = comment.TaskID;

            return PartialView("_GetForTask", comments);
        }
```

Comment: You really don't need _TaskCommentForm action. Just display the partial view inside _GetForTask.cshtml.

Comment: _TaskCommentForm is where I intend to accept new comments. I'm doing something like that of a facebook comment. But I'll try to remove it and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: It just displays the partial view. You can also do it by calling Html.Partial.

Comment: _TaskCommentForm action passes a new instance of TaskComment to the _TaskCommentForm partial view. Without this action, how do I pass a new instance of TaskComment to the partial view. Thanks again.

Comment: `@Html.Partial("_TaskCommentForm", new TaskComment { TaskID = ViewBag.TaskID })`

Comment: Tried that now it's giving me a new error Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'. and it's pointing to @Html.Action("_GetForTask", "TaskComment", new { TaskID = Model.TaskID })

Comment: You need to replace that line with the Html.Partial call I just posted. You are also displaying a form inside another form in your view. Have you noticed that?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my questions. Really appreciate it! But apparently, the signature of my _Submit action method should have been                                                             public PartialViewResult _Submit(TaskComment taskComment)